# Cypress not stubbing json data in intercept?

Tags: next.js, cypress

I've been searching for a solution all day, googling and StackOverflowing, but nothing appears to be working.

I've got a very simple NextJS app. On page load, I load a fact from a third party API automatically. Then a user can enter a search query, press enter, and search again based on that query. I want to create a Cypress test that checks for the functionality of that search feature.

Right now, I'm getting a timeout on `cy.wait()`, and it states that `No request ever occurred.`

*app.spec.js*

```js
import data from '../fixtures/data';

describe('Test search functionality', () => {
  it('renders new fact when search is performed', () => {

    // Visit page
    cy.visit('/');

    // Wait for page to finish loading initial fact
    cy.wait(1000);

    // Intercept call to API
    cy.intercept("GET", `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT}/jokes/search?query=Test`, {
      fixture: "data.json",
    }).as("fetchFact");

    // Type in search input
    cy.get('input').type('Test');

    // Click on search button
    cy.get('.submit-btn').click();

    // Wait for the request to be made
    cy.wait('@fetchFact').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);

    cy.get('p.copy').should('contain', data.result[0].value);
  })
});
```

One thing I've noticed, is that the data being displayed on the page is coming from the actual API response, rather than the json file I'm attempting to stub with. None of React code is written server-side either, this is all client-side.

As you can see, the test is pretty simple, and I feel like I've tried every variation of intercept, changing order of things, etc. What could be causing this timeout? Why isn't the json being stubbed correctly in place of the network request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And of course, I figure out the issue minutes after posting this question.

I realized that Cypress doesn't like Next's way of handling env variables, and instead needed to create a `cypress.env.json`. I've updated my test to look like this:

```js
import data from '../fixtures/data';

describe('Test search functionality', () => {
  it('renders new fact when search is performed', () => {

    // Visit page
    cy.visit('/');

    // Wait for page to finish loading initial fact
    cy.wait(1000);

    // Intercept call to API
    const url = `${Cypress.env('apiEndpoint')}/jokes/search?query=Test`;
    cy.intercept("GET", url, {
      fixture: "data",
    }).as("fetchFact");

    // Type in search input
    cy.get('input').type('Test');

    // Click on search button
    cy.get('.submit-btn').click();

    // Wait for the request to be made
    cy.wait('@fetchFact').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);

    cy.get('p.copy').should('contain', data.result[0].value);
  })
});
```